# Colour connotations in Japanese language?

Tags: culture

In English cultures there is a thin line (that usually isn't crossed) between symbolism (usually used in visual arts) and lingual connotation which is usually used in creative writing, and colour is a large medium for both. Lets take blue for example. In a painting I would use blue to represent eternity, a sort of ongoing feeling; like that of the sky or ocean. In a story or a poem I would use blue to signify depression or solemness. I have looked for something like the Japanese equivalent but I have only found Japanese colour symbolism.

Colours are used often to represent ideas and social attitudes, like gold commonly being the iconic colour of Buddhism in older Japanese art, and blue sometimes representing daily life (because indigo dye was very common). However, what I want to know is if colour didn't just serve symbolic use in visual art, but in writing as well. Does Japanese have different lingual connotations for the colours that are separate from the connotation used in symbolism? If possible could you give an example and any helpful resources?

**Edit:** I'm asking if there is any symbolic use of colours in Japanese *language*, separate from the symbolic use of and meaning derived from colour symbolism in imagery, like in the example with blue written above.

Comment: "... and any other colours I left out": You are asking for a complete analysis of colours in Japanese. This sounds more like a PhD thesis to me. To get a meaningful answer on this site, you'll have to be more specific about what you don't understand. e.g. "Does 赤 carry the meaning of aggression and passion, like it does in English?" or "Is there any example of a colour in Japanese that carries symbolism, which the same colour doesn't carry in English?"

Comment: @user1205935 Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: You say that you "have only found Japanese colour symbolism". Could you explain what you found and what you consider to be particularly Japanese about this symbolism?

Comment: Alright, thanks for the edit. Now it is a question ;)

Comment: @user1205935 Thanks a lot for the tips! Really helpful!

Comment: I don't understand how anyone can answer this question satisfactorily.

Comment: @user18597 It can be answered if someone points out that Japanese does or does not have connotation of colour in the language and hopefully an example. That would be satisfactory.

Comment: I've been reading this question many times over now, but I still don't understand what's being asked. A casual reading suggests you want "symbolic use of color in Japanese language" (what's "symbolic use"?), but then you say "separate from ... meaning derived from ... imagery", which seems like saying you don't want anything where the meaning originated in the actual color (say white=purity.) Even if such a word and meaning does exist, how does one prove that? Plus all your blue examples have their meanings rooted in the actual color.

I'm confused!

Comment: @KohsukeKawaguchi In an image one could use a colour to represent something, but the use of the very same colour in language can have a different meaning. I already know what colours mean in Japanese arts in a visual sense, but I don't know what sort of connotation is assigned to colours when written or spoken, if such a thing exists in Japanese like it does in English.

Comment: @user18597 perhaps if there was a separate question for each colour, but even then, I think that you would need to have a further set of questions for each colour

Comment: @axrwkr I was thinking in general, like is it [colour connotations] even there to begin with, and an example to move on from.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I still don't really understand what you are asking, but I guess the only way to find out is to try a few examples to see if any one matches your criteria.

- 赤 is often used to mean *bareness* and *nakedness*: 赤子(baby) 赤裸々(blunt) 赤貧 (very poor). Not sure about the origin, but can't think of any obvious visual origin to this meaning.
- 白 is used to represent innocence as in 「あいつはシロだ」. Originally a police jargon but I think it's now common enough. More commonly written as シロ instead of 白. The meaning has obvious visual origin of white being pure. (クロ has the opposite meaning.)

Comment: For 白, there is also 頭の中が真っ白になる, expressing that one's mind goes blank.

Comment: あか meanings are from あかるい. I think it's the same origin, and then got bent to mean "red".

Comment: @Dono I'm well aware that there are all sorts of meanings originated from the actual visual color (especially white). I didn't bother listing them as I wasn't sure what Koasamitsu really wants to know.

Comment: @user18597 I've never heard that the word 赤 originates from 明るい, and 明るい do not have any bareness/nakedness meaning. Do you have any sources?

Comment: @KohsukeKawaguchi - this is well-known. I don't have academic sources but see e.g. http://gogen-allguide.com/a/aka.html

Comment: 赤 and 明るい have the common origin; see [Daijisen](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&stype=1&dtype=0&dname=0na&p=%E8%B5%A4%E3%81%84) and [Daijirin](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&stype=1&dtype=0&dname=0ss&p=%E8%B5%A4%E3%81%84).  I do not know whether the original meaning is 明るい or not.

Comment: OK, I guess I learn something new every day!